# How to avoid using too many && and ||

Tags: java

```
package CurrencyConverter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrencyConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Currency Converter"
               + " \"MONEY MONEY KACHINGG\"\n ");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter desired amount: ");
        double amount = s.nextDouble();
    //----------------Supported Amount------------------------------------------    
        if(amount < 0 || amount > 1000) {
            System.out.println("Amount must be between 0 and 1000");
            return; }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------           
        System.out.print("Type currency to START FROM: ");
        String from = s.next();
        System.out.print("Type currency to CONVERT TO: ");
        String to = s.next();

        double currency;
    //-----------------------UNSUPPORTED------------- ---------------------------   
        if((!from.equals("BGN") && !to.equals("USD")) && 
           (!from.equals("USD") && !to.equals("BGN"))) {

            System.out.println("Unsupported Currency!\n"
                   + "Please choose from BGN or USD"); }
    //------------------------BGN to USD----------------------------------------   
        else if(from.equals("BGN") && to.equals("USD")) {
           for(currency = 0; currency <= amount; currency++) {
               System.out.printf("%.2f leva = %.2f $\n",currency,(currency/1.52)); }
            }
    //------------------------USD to BGN----------------------------------------    
        else if(from.equals("USD") && to.equals("BGN")) {
            for(currency = 0; currency <= amount; currency++) {
                System.out.printf("%.2f $ = %.2f leva\n",currency,(currency/1.52)); }
            }
    //------------------------Incorrect-----------------------------------------    
        else {
            System.out.println("Unsupported Currency!\n"
                    + "Please choose from BGN or USD"); }
```

Is there an easier way to tell which currency is allowed and which is not? (**See UNSUPPORTED**).

I was told that so many && or || are not good for the code. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code review. **If the code is working as-is**, please post it there.

Comment: Define 'too many'. Compared to what? Why are you asking us, instead of the source of this meaningless statement?

Comment: Im sorry I am new here, where can I do that

Comment: @Mr.Rendero codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The "unsupported" and "incorrect" blocks are identical. Why is the "unsupported" block even there?

Comment: It seems I can't close the question after it has been answered, only flag is allowed. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's not true that many `||` or `&&` is bad coding. Having *excess* is not good though. In your case since you only support two types of conversion you can simplify things:

```
    if(from.equals("BGN") && to.equals("USD")) {
       for(currency = 0; currency <= amount; currency++) {
           System.out.printf("%.2f leva = %.2f $\n",currency,(currency/1.52)); }
    }
    else if(from.equals("USD") && to.equals("BGN")) {
        for(currency = 0; currency <= amount; currency++) {
            System.out.printf("%.2f $ = %.2f leva\n",currency,(currency/1.52)); }
    }
    else {
    //unsupported
    }
```

Previously you were checking for unsupported conversions twice: in the first **if**, and also implicitly in the last **else**. Also I should point out that you are doing the same conversion in both cases, so something is likely wrong there.

Comment: You are right, thank you.